# docker: client is newer than server

Tags: linux, docker

**Disclaimer:** I know, there are several questions dealing with this problem (e.g. “[Newer docker client with older Docker host](https://serverfault.com/questions/664999/newer-docker-client-with-older-docker-host)” or “[Error response from daemon: client is newer than server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015271/error-response-from-daemon-client-is-newer-than-server)”). But none of them is actually targeting the full complexity and I'm not dealing with boot2docker.

**Circumstances**

I have a setup of a client-computer (my laptop) and four docker daemons (1× local, 3× remote on different servers).
When I try to manage one of the remote docker daemons I frequently get messages like:

```
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: X, server API version: Y)
```

(where `X > Y` and usually `|X-Y| ≤ 0.3`; e.g. `X = 1.21, Y = 1.19`)

In most cases the cause is, that my client computer has a quite up-to-date system, while the servers are usually staying with older versions and shouldn't be frequently unavailable for updates.
Additionally, if I would always update the servers, I would have to update all three servers together and everybody else who is using the servers in turn has to update their clients. (While the group of collaborators is different for each of the servers.)

**Question**

Is there any way to setup my client, that it can communicate with different older API versions?

(Why is the docker project not able to provide some kind of backward compatibility at least within minor versions?)

Comment: What is the client host OS in this case?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [github comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11486#issuecomment-92500367) docker clients can talk to newer servers but newer clients cannot talk to older servers. So you can go ahead and update your docker servers but you should also push your users to update their clients because there are definitely limits to the compatibility.

There's a proposed [pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15964) that will allow you to specify the API Version that your client uses when talking to the server but it hasn't been accepted yet.